# Error when initializing Stage

Tags: java, libgdx, screen, initialization

I made a new class that implements Screen, what I've seen from other people's code is that they create a constructor that takes a parameter of Game game. I did not created a constructor, I think that's the reason why I get the error

```
  public class MainMenu implements Screen{
     public MainMenu(Game game){ //I dont know what are these for
            this.game = game;    //<--
        }


 public void show() {
        btnAtlas=new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("bitters.atlas"));
        skin=new Skin();
        skin.addRegions(btnAtlas);
        stage=new Stage(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),true);// I get the error here when initializing the Stage
    }
 }
```

the error is `"Cannon resolve constructor 'Stage(int,int,boolean)'"`

Answer (score 2):

The message is pretty clear. There is no constructor that takes `(int, int, boolean)`. Here are the constructors from [Stage.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/Stage.java) source code.

[image: 1]

Comment: So I need to create a new class for the stage? and use one of these constructors

Comment: @masterYao09 Either edit the libgdx source code or create a Stage class that extends `com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage` and add a constructor that does what you need. But I am pretty sure that the libgdx constructor is enough to work with.